# Special characters displaying incorrectly after BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert, nvarchar

I'm using `BULK INSERT` to import a CSV file. One of the columns in the CSV file contains some values that contain fractions (e.g. `1m½f`).

I don't need to do any mathematical operations on the fractions, as the values will just be used for display purposes, so I have set the column as `nvarchar`. The `BULK INSERT` works but when I view the records within SQL the fraction has been replaced with a cent symbol (`¢`) so the displayed text is `1m¢f`.

I'm interested to understand why this is happening and any thoughts on how to resolve the issue. The `BULK INSERT` command is:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.temp FROM 'C:\Temp\file.csv' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' );
```

Comment: Does the data literally contain the one-half character?

Comment: Yes, it contains the ½ character as opposed to 1/2.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, the Bulk Insert is:

`code`
BULK INSERT dbo.temp  
FROM 'C:\Temp\file.csv'  
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' );  
   
The Collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS.  
  
How do I check if the file is marked as Unicode?

Comment: You can check if the file is Unicode by, for example, opening it in Notepad and then going to File > Save As. Depending on the version of Windows you should see an "Encoding" drop-down somewhere with options like ANSI,  UTF-8, Unicode, Unicode big endian...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks - it shows ANSI.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to `BULK INSERT` using the `CODEPAGE = 'ACP'`, which converts string data from Windows codepage 1252 to SQL Server codepage.

```
BULK INSERT dbo.temp FROM 'C:\Temp\file.csv' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', CODEPAGE = 'ACP');
```

If you are bringing in UTF-8 data on a new enough version of SQL Server:

```
[...] , CODEPAGE = '65001');
```

You may also need to specify `DATAFILETYPE = 'char|native|widechar|widenative'`.

Comment: This was also what I needed to correctly bulk insert ansii text with accented characters, such as è, in it.

Comment: Thank you @aaron bertrand. It worked partially for me. I am facing issues while inserting accented characters. For example: ä is shown as Ã¤

Comment: @user1417294 What is the encoding of the file, the data type and collation of the column, and the collation of the database and instance?