# How to properly convert accented characters using FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, encoding, for-xml-path

I'm trying to take a string in SQL Server that contains an accented character (the acute e specifically) and have it convert correctly when using FOR XML PATH as follows:

```
SELECT 'é' AS Accent
FOR XML PATH('')

/* Produces: <Accent>&eacute;</Accent> */
```

However, it always comes through with the accent, or tries to convert the other characters instead. This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT 'é' AS Accent
FOR XML PATH('')

/* Produces: <Accent>é</Accent> */

SELECT N'é' AS Accent
FOR XML PATH('')

/* Produces: <Accent>é</Accent> */

SELECT REPLACE('é', 'é', '&eacute;') AS Accent
FOR XML PATH('')

/* Produces: <Accent>&amp;eacute;</Accent> */

SELECT '<![CDATA[' + 'é' + ']]>' AS Accent
FOR XML PATH('')

/* Produces: <Accent>&lt;![CDATA[é]]&gt;</Accent> */

SELECT CAST('<![CDATA[' + 'é' + ']]>' AS XML) AS Accent
FOR XML PATH('')

/* Produces: <Accent>é</Accent> */
```

I've looked for quite a while and can't find anything apart from casting the end result XML into a string and manually replacing the character - I'm looking for a more correct way to do this. Is this just a bug in SQL Server? It seems to convert plenty of other characters (<, >, &, etc...).

Huge thanks in advance for any assistance.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: There's nothing wrong with `<Accent>é</Accent>` actually, but - for any reason - you need this to be `<Accent>&eacute;</Accent>`?

Comment: @Shnugo correct - the XML outputted by this is imported by another system that can't read the accented character correctly without it being converted.

Comment: Your first "What I tried says "Produces: <Accent>é</Accent> */".  I'm confused.

Comment: @SQLDBA correct - the first query in the "What I tried" section outputs <Accent>é</Accent>

Comment: I see.  You want it to look like "&eacute;".  Is the other system using BULK IMPORT?  The CODEPAGE option can solve the import issue.  I've run into that before.  Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx

Comment: See this SO question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996967/special-characters-displaying-incorrectly-after-bulk-insert

Comment: @SQLDBA I unfortunately don't have access to the other system, but I know it's loaded into Postgres using a Java program. Thanks for the link though, I've never used BULK IMPORT before. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I'd assume, that this is not possible without a hack.

SQL-Server treats XML as 2 byte `utf-16` internally. So all characters, which are displayable within this range do not need escaping.

It is a different thing, when it comes to unprintable characters or letters, which have a declarative meaning, like `<, > and &` or quotes (in some cases).

I'd probably use a cast to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and then a replace on string level at the point where you export this data. You won't be able to cast this back to XML:

--Push your test XML into a variable

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
(
    SELECT 'é' AS Accent
    FOR XML PATH('')
);
SELECT @xml; --<Accent>é</Accent>
```

--Cast it to string and do the replacement on string-level

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'é', '&eacute;') --<Accent>&eacute;</Accent>
```

--Trying to cast this result back to XML fails

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'é', '&eacute;') AS XML);
```

> XML parsing: line 1, character 16, well formed check: undeclared entity

Obvioulsy SQL Server's XML engine doesn't even know this entity...

Comment: Bummer. My main issue with this is the size of the XML that needs to go through this - probably best to do it outside SQL Server. Thanks a ton for your above example and explanation. If I don't get anything else I'll accept this as the answer.