# How to retrieve German characters from a large CSV File into SQL Server 2017 script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, nvarchar, sql-server-collation

I have a CSV file including a list of employees, where some of them includes German characters like 'ö' in their names. I need to create a temp table in my SQL Server 2017 script and fill it with the content of the CSV file. My script is:

```
CREATE TABLE #AllAdUsers(
    [PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [DisplayName] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [Company] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [SAMAccountName] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL
)

--import AD users
BULK INSERT #AllAdUsers
    FROM 'C:\Employees.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
        TABLOCK
    )
```

However, even though I use "Nvarchar" variable type with the collation of "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI", the German characters are not seem OK, for instance "Kösker" seems like:

```
"K├╢sker"
```

I've tried many other collations but couldn't find a fix for it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is the CSV file encoded using UTF-8? If so may try codepage 65001 (or ACP). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997372/61305) from a long, long time ago.

Comment: @AaronBertrand omg thank you very much !!

Comment: What was the encoding of the source file? What change to your BULK INSERT code fixed it?

Comment: codepage 65001 fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `codepage=65001` to the bulk insert query fixed the issue:

```
--import AD users
BULK INSERT #AllAdUsers
    FROM 'C:\Employees.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        CODEPAGE = '65001',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
        TABLOCK
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the ***Encoding*** of your source CSV file to ***UTF-8*** with Notepad++ and try to import it again.

It worked for me.

Comment: that could be another solution, thanks for the suggestion, but it requires a manual procedure in the middle. The CSV file here was being generated by another application and I needed to read it immediately via a SQL job after another application stopped running.